# Firebase: modify/update string number

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So im trying every time a button is clicked to update the value of the `itemcategory` child which is a  string number in firebase, by adding 1 to this value. Please dont suggest me to convert this string to integer by removing `""`. It is very important for me to be a string.

My Firebase structure:

[image: My Firebase structure]

This is my code

```
 final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(ID).child("itemcategory");
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              //how to get the current value of itemcategory field?
              //how to modify it and add +1 to this string number?
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Im coping with this 3 weeks and havent find any solution.
As i wrote in the comments i have 2 questions:

1. how to get the current value of itemcategory field?
2. how to modify it and add +1 to this string number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way retrieve the value convert it to integer then add it and store as string.

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(ID);
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String number = dataSnapshot.child("itemcategory").getValue(String.class);
        int value = Integer.parseInt(number);
        int newValue = value + 1;
        mDatabase.child("itemcategory").setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: do i need a dependency for this? because i get ```cannot resolve method update(?)```

Comment: On which method it's causing problem

Comment: in this line ```mDatabase.update({ itemcategory: String.valueOf(newValue)});``` i get ```cannot resolve method update(?)```, and also the itemcategory keyword is red

Comment: It just deleted the whole child and made a new one like this 31209482454:  "6", incredible

Comment: @undercoverpolicevan oh sorry. please check updated answer i mistakenly forgot to put child after database ref.

Comment: thank you so much, you cant image how happy i am! <3 have a good day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216924/discussion-between-undercoverpolicevan-and-ashish).

Answer (score 2):

If you're updating a node based on its current value, consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for this. Without a transaction you run the risk that multiple users end up overwriting each others values.

In your code it'd look something like:

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(ID).child("itemcategory");

postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        String value = mutableData.getValue(String.class);
        int number;
        if (string == null) {
            number = 0;
        }
        else {
            number = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        number = number + 1

        mutableData.setValue(String.valueOf(number));

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed,
                           DataSnapshot currentData) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```